# Meta boxes not showing up

Tags: metabox, hooks, callbacks

Okay so I'm trying to render a meta box.

This is what I have so far, trying to keep it as basic as possible:

```
add_action('load-post.php', 'ad_templates_callback' );
add_action('load-post-new.php', 'ad_templates_callback' );

function ad_templates_callback(){
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'ad_templates_add_meta_box');
    add_action('save_post', 'ad_templates_save_post');
}

function ad_templates_add_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box( 'ad_templates', 'Template Options', 'ad_templates_render', 'page', 'normal', 'default');
}

function ad_templates_render($object, $box){
    wp_nonce_field( basename(__FILE__), 'ad_templates_nonce' );
    global $post_id;
    ?>
        <p>
            balblabl test
        </p>
    <?php
}
function ad_templates_save_post(){
    //nothing
}
```

I have no idea why, but it doesn't show up on either the New Page or existing Page pages.

I've tried it with removing the 'load-post.php' hooks and I've tried it with using Posts instead of Pages.

I've copied this code from an earlier WP theme I've created (which successfully shows the boxes), with a slight edit to the theme slug. 
So somewhere, somehow I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I just went full potato and forgot to include the file into my functions.php

Is there any way to delete this question?